# Shared element transition Android Q

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation, shared-element-transition

I have noticed a problem with shared element transition between fragments on android Q.

The shared view is an `imageView` from a recycle view list element. When I move from fragment A to fragment B, the shared transition works fine, but when I press back from fragment B to fragment A, the imageView is white, basically the image is gone.

on fragment A :

```
 val extras = FragmentNavigator.Extras.Builder()
                .addSharedElement(sharedImage, product.id())
                .build()

        val args = Bundle()

        args.putString("productImage", product.id())

        ViewCompat.setTransitionName(sharedImage, product.id())

        findNavController().navigate(R.id.productFragment, args, null, extras)
```

on fragment B :

```
    transitionName = arg.get("productImage") as String
    ViewCompat.setTransitionName(imageView, transitionName)
```

how it looks after i press back:

[image]

The problem is only on android Q.

> Blockquote

Comment: I have a similiar problem.